# How come you can't run duplicate JQuery plugins on a single page?

Tags: php, html, jquery, plugins

I recently downloaded a JQuery rotating banner plugin from: http://www.mclelun.com/labs/#jqbanner. I noticed that when I have one rotating banner on my page it works brilliantly, however when I try to add another one, only one of them, the first rotating banner will work. The second one will not work.

How do I get both rotating banners to work simultaneously?

Below is my code:

```
//##########################################
//###### The first Banner rotator ##########
//##########################################

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqbanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqbanner.css" />
```

Include the list of banners To tell the script which images in your page are for rotating banners.

```
<div id="jqb_object">

<div class="jqb_slides">
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner1.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner2.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title"><a href="slide link"><img src="banner3.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><span>TEXT SLIDE IN DIV</span></div></div>

<div class="jqb_bar">
<div class="jqb_info"></div>
<div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
<div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_pause"></div>
<div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

The above will work. However when I try to add a new banner like the code below, the second banner rotator will not work:

```
//##########################################
//###### The second Banner rotator #########
//##########################################

<div id="jqb_object">

<div class="jqb_slides">
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner1.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner2.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title"><a href="slide link"><img src="banner3.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><span>TEXT SLIDE IN DIV</span></div></div>

<div class="jqb_bar">
<div class="jqb_info"></div>
<div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
<div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_pause"></div>
<div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is jqbanner.js directly referencing the jqb_object ID? I'm guessing that's what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that you have 2 elements with the same id: `<div id="jqb_object">`

If the add-in is working based on selecting an element with this id, it will not work for multiples, since when matching a selector that is by id, jQuery returns the first element it finds in the page.

So the code will never be run on the second div with the id.

---

If you wish to have multiple banners, update the code to work on elements with a class (which should be used to identify a number of elements) and have multiple divs:

e.g. `<div id="banner1" class="jqb_object">` and `<div id="banner2" class="jqb_object">`, which can be selected with:

```
$('.jqb_object')
```

It looks like the line you want to start experimenting with is jqbanner.js:71

```
$("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide")
```

Start by trying

```
$('.jqb_object').find('.jqb_slide')
```

Answer (score 1):

What StuperUser said, plus this -

I think the plugin you're using, jqbanner, is designed with the idea that you'd only have one banner on a page. Otherwise, it would be constructed in such a way that you'd have a method to call on multiple objects.

For instance, with the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), which does something similar, you can call the cycle method on as many objects as you want, like so:

```
$('#div_id_1, #div_id_2').cycle();
```

This is also a lesson on why ID's need to be unique - that is, you can only have one instance of an ID per page. Both of your banners have the same ID, leading to this collision.